# Malloc() doesn't work + char array clear

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

First question: 
    I have some keys and values in a Redis database. I read them with the following command: `redisReply *reply = redisCommand(c, "HGETALL %s", test_id);`
Then I want to create a char array where I want to put them in like this: "key=value; key2=value2;" etc.
So I am trying to use malloc() to allocate memory for a char array. I do the following:

```
int token_length;
for (i = 0; i < reply->elements; i = i + 2 ) 
  token_length = strlen(reply->element[i]->str)+strlen(reply->element[i+1]->str)+3;

tokens = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*token_length);
memset(tokens, '\0' , sizeof(tokens));

for (i = 0; i < reply->elements; i = i + 2 ) {
      strcat(tokens,reply->element[i]->str);
      strcat(tokens,"=");
      strcat(tokens,reply->element[i+1]->str);
      strcat(tokens,"; ");
  }
```

I get the correct number with token_length, but if I use it in malloc(...) I get memory error, etc.  Instead, if I just put 150 instead of token_length in malloc(), it works great. Why is that?

Second question: if I do not do `memset(tokens, '\0' , sizeof(tokens));`
after `malloc()`, I get a lot of "rubbish" inside my token array. Should someone always clear a char array after allocation with `malloc()`? Is there another, maybe better, way?

Third Question: When I output the array instead of the character ";", I get \073 which is the octal representation of ";" in the ASCII table.

Comment: One question per question please! Also, why are you calculating `token_length` multiple times, then ignoring all but the last value ?

Comment: 1st question: Your code sample above is likely different from your actual code sample that produces the behavior you described, as there is no reason that `tokens = malloc(sizeof(char)*150);` would behave differently from `int token_length = 150; tokens = malloc(sizeof(char)*token_length);`

Comment: 2nd question: Read about [null-terminated strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string)

Comment: 1) Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C. 2) `sizeof(char)` will never return anything different from `1`, so it is useless.

Comment: `token_length = ` --> `token_length += `

Comment: `malloc` works just fine

Comment: Also initialize `token_length` before that .

Comment: .  You never need to multiply by `sizeof(char)` as `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition

Comment: ok thanks everyone for the help, forgetting the += for the token_length was very stupid , i was focusing on malloc instead. Also initializing the token_length was a must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems - rather than describe each bug individually I'll just post a fixed version and you can compare it with your original code:

```
int token_length = 0; // <<< initialise
for (i = 0; i < reply->elements; i = i + 2 ) 
    token_length += strlen(reply->element[i]->str)+strlen(reply->element[i+1]->str)+3; // <<< use += to accumulate length

tokens = malloc(token_length + 1); // <<< need extra char for '\0' terminator
tokens[0] = '\0';                  // (also don't cast result of malloc() in C !)

for (i = 0; i < reply->elements; i = i + 2 ) {
    strcat(tokens,reply->element[i]->str);
    strcat(tokens,"=");
    strcat(tokens,reply->element[i+1]->str);
    strcat(tokens,"; ");
}
```

Comment: thanks, it seems to work now ... !

Answer (score 0):

```
int token_length=0;
for (i = 0; i < reply->elements; i = i + 2 ) 
  token_length += strlen(reply->element[i]->str)+strlen(reply->element[i+1]->str)+3;
```

Comment: forgetting the += and the initialization was so stupid ... thanks